# App node auto deletes with no error on server

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I've got an old Vue project that I'm trying to update into a subfolder so I updated its baseURL to the subfolder and re-built the project. It works fine on local but when uploaded, I noticed that the app node auto deletes upon loading with no error messages in the console so I end up with a blank page. As there are no errors and works fine on `npm run serve` locally, I'm not too sure how to go about debugging this. Here's the URL -> https://lab.kelvinzhao.com/tooth/ Did anyone happen to come across this issue before and know why this happens?

Comment: Instead of describing the problem in text, please edit your question to include the minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I understand that for normal cases where I can isolate or find at least some error I'd definitely post it, but in this case, there is nothing for me to catch on to why this is happening which is why I'm searching for anyone who encountered such an issue previously. It just turns into a blank page with no errors.

Comment: The app is served and displayed despite lacking expected content. So there's no reason to suspect Webpack's `baseUrl` (you would get an actual blank white page). Start by showing main.js, App.vue, and/or any relevant code, including conditionals and anything dependent upon an external API.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Solved!** Spent half a day to test out all the various possibilities through similar errors others faced. It was a combination of two errors which doesn't produce any console errors which is why it was so tough to find out why. Two things needed to be changed to fix this.

1. As it is an old Vue project, under `index.js` under the config folder the `assetsPublicPath:` it needs to be changed to the subfolder. Currently, the new way of doing things is under the `vue.config.js` which doesn't exist previously.
2. Under Vue router, a `base: 'tooth'` needed to be added. There was quite a confusion on this part as the official documentation said `base: '/tooth/'` should be added instead, but I've tried and it doesn't work, the slashes / needs to be removed, not sure why it's there in the documentation.